# Can we reach a server running inside kubernetes Cluster from Outside?

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform

I have a requirement that the server that is running inside one of my container in a k8s cluster should be able to reach a server that is running in some other machine (currently its in AWS).Now the problem is that both the server (in AWS & Kubernetes Cluster) should be able to reach each other.

My server in AWS is not able to ping my Server running in Kubernetes Cluster.

**Is that possible? Can we do it ?**

Comment: You just need them to see each other? Where is your cluster (managed Kubernetes service/on-premise/cloud VM?)

Comment: got your answer ? make ingress object

Comment: Yeah Ingress will serve the purpose

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use ingress-nginx to create publicly reachable services [ingress-nginx](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx)

If you want to do it manually you can setup load balancers that map to specific ip ranges for your nodes. This is for ssh traffic.

Answer (score 1):

yes you can use ingress kubernetes object it will create publicly reachable services.

Mainly if you are using aws or digital-ocean and you will use ingress it will make load balancer (ELB or ALB) and make public service and you can access server running inside kubernetes

By manually also you can do it just simply use kubernetes service and expose it using load balancer and NODE port

```
https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/
```